# Sumif using page, report and visual level filters

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns

I have two tables that are related by an ID column called 'Program_Code' (1:Many).

'Program_Summary':

- Program Code = each row has a unique ID, e.g. HI-18, HI-17
- Program Name = name of a program, e.g. Home Improvement
- Incentive Spending = calculate(sum(Program_Data[Incentives]))

'Program_Data':

- Program Code = many rows with the same ID
- Incentives = incentive amount to summarize in Program Summary table
- Record Status = Claimed, Pipeline or Rejected
- Record Fiscal Year = 2017, 2018 or 2019

I created a Power BI table that has rows organized by 'Program Name'. Note that each program name like "Home Improvement" may have more than one code associated with it, e.g. HI-18 and HI-17 corresponding to fiscal years.

I'm hoping to summarize Incentive Spending by program name, and use page/report level filters to restrict results. The Report Level filters are:

- Record Fiscal Year = 2017
- Record Status = Claimed

But, the calculate(sum(Program_Data[Incentives])) filter ignores these page level filters. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created "Incentive Spending" as a calculated column. Instead, you need to create it as a **measure**.

Calculated columns are calculated only once - when you create them, or when you reload data. After that, calculated columns contain only static data, and can not respond to any filters.

Measures, on the other hand, are dynamic formulas that recalculate any time you change any filters.

To fix your problem, simply create a new measure from "Modeling" tab:

[image]

and add DAX code:

```
Incentive Spending = SUM(Program_Data[Incentives])
```

(no need to use CALCULATE here).

Drop this measure into a table or matrix, and it should work. Instead of page/report level filters, I'd recommend to use slicers - create a slicer for Fiscal Year, and another slicer for Record Status. They will allow you to filter the calculation with ease.

Comment: This is a revelation! So please pardon my beginner response: what's the point of columns if it turns out creating a measure is much more useful? One thing that pops out for me is columns that come from my original query. These columns are included in filters, so it's strange to me that new columns would not be. Unless I create a 'measure' instead of a column.

Comment: Power BI is all about measures. Calculated columns are abominations that should be avoided. They are mostly used when you do quick prototyping, and realized that your source data is missing a field you need. After prototyping is done, calculated columns should be moved to the source data (i,e, calculated in a database, or in PowerQuery).  In other words, calculated columns are a symptom of data modeling mistake. Get your model right, and you will never need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
CALCULATE(sum(Program_Data[Incentives]);Program_Data[Record Fiscal Year] = 2017 && Program_Data[Record Status] = "Claimed")
```

However, I do not understand why you would need this because you have 2 tables with the right link, this should give you all possibilities with the table/matrix visualization what you need to show correct results..

Comment: I used a very simple example I guess to show a problem I was having with slicers and filters not effecting my calculated column. I wanted to create some new columns that contain formulas as well. But sounds like I need to use measures as per the other answer?